# Google cloud logging has label

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I can run the query `labels:*` or `logName:*` which works, however the following query doesn't match anything ,even though these labels exist:

`labels.user:*`

**Reproducable example:**

Take any log resource and try
`labels:*`, then see they all have some value X under their label. then try
`labels.X:*`, see there are no results

Comment: Please can you provide the full query? How are you executing this?

Comment: This is the full query. I executed it via the Java, the web interface and gcloud...I'll come up with a gcloud cli example to reproduce, if possible to add labels there

Comment: It's not possible to add via gcloud. I added an example which you can reproduce with already existing logs

Comment: I've worked around by ingesting the data with '-' field. But still it seems like a bug or unsupported feature at best..

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. The issue is being investigated by the engineers. I've opened an issue tracker on your behalf for this matter and you can follow the investigation updates via this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/120598899)